# Starting long-running process from within Apache ServiceMix

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-servicemix

I am looking for suggestions or ideas.

There is an external process (or even a browser) that needs to trigger a long-running process via simple web service call that ideally should run in the same container as that web service. We're using Apache ServiceMix. The web service itself shouldn't stay alive for the duration of the long-running process, besides it may just time-out anyway so we want it to return the response normally pretty much right away.

Originally, I was thinking of using ProcessBuilder() to launch the long-running process as just another app but doing this introduces certain OS dependencies and seems like a less then ideal practice anyway. One of the options we considered is starting another thread from the request and just letting the request complete immediately with a response while the long-running thread would keep on going as long as needed. I fear resource hijacking on the container as well as long-running thread's health when its launcher/parent exits losing any reference to that long-running child.

If anyone has any good ideas for how this can be solved in an elegant way, please let me know.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here as you didn't provide the version of your servicemix. Though with Camel which is included with servicemix I'd have two routes the first one providing the web service the second one doing the long running process. The second route should use the seda component. This will give you the async call.